# Gameobject instantiated in canvas shows up behind other canvas items

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, perspectivecamera, gameobject

In my game, if it is the first time the player has ever played the game then I have an image that is displayed. I instantiate it in the canvas like so:

```
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("First Time", 1) == 1)
    {
        introEnabled = true;

        //pause all activity
        pause.pauseOrResume();

        intro = Instantiate (Resources.Load ("intro"), transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        Canvas canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas>();
        intro.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
        //robot = Instantiate (Resources.Load ("robot"), transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("First Time", 0);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
```

I can see in the inspector when the game is running that when the object is created, it does show up in the canvas. I just have no idea why it won't show up on top of all of the other objects in the canvas.

The canvas rendering mode is set to "Screen space - Overlay" and it is set to 0 in the sort order. The game object being instantiated also has a sort order of 0 and it is in the default layer.

Nothing I have tried has worked. The z values make no difference and even putting the canvas and the instantiated object in the Default layer and setting the canvas to a sort order of 2 and the instantiated object to a sort order of 1 (so it is rendered first) does not make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to use [`transform.SetAsLastSibling()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetAsLastSibling.html) . The `CanvasRenderer` renders the `GameObject`s in order according to their sibling index's (position in the hierarchy), from top to bottom.

However, after examining your code further I noticed something and I should say that if you are trying to instantiate the intro screen, I would highly recommend to instantiate it with it's own `Canvas`, instead of parenting it to the existing one. Something that significant should have it's own dedicated `Canvas`.

Update: The problem here is that you are instantiating `GameObjects` with a `transform` and `Sprite` renderer. `Canvas` UI gets rendered last, over all mesh layers, so if you want your newly instantiated `GameObjects` to participate, they will need to have `RectTransform` and `Image` components instead.

Comment: After adding transform.SetAsLastSibling() to both the canvas and the newly instantiated game objects in separate attempts, the newly instantiated game object still shows up behind the old canvas items.

Comment: And they have `RectTransform`s? And `Image` components?

Comment: The newly instantiated game object has a transform and a sprite renderer. That is it. It is a prefab that I am instantiating.

Comment: Well thats the problem then.

Comment: What is? What do I need to change?

Comment: is that "sprite.enabled = false;" supposed to be a different name? what should sprite be? I'm guessing introImage? That is the only thing with that property. And also the mainTexture of the image is read only.

Comment: that should still be introImage, not introSprite. Sprites do not have that property. And is there a way to get around the mainTexture of introImage being read only?

Comment: dam okay I think your just going to have to edit them by hand. on the prefab basically just remove the `Sprite`, add a `RectTransform` (which will automatically replace your existing `transform`), then add `Image` and set it up just as your sprite was.

Comment: Now it isn't visible at all. I added the RectTransform and the Image and added the sprite to the image component yet when it is instantiated or if i just add it to the inspector, there is nothing there.

Comment: can you link a screenshot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87182/discussion-between-saboehnke-and-andrew).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Default layer **change its layer to UI.**

Comment: For which one? The canvas or the newly instantiated object?

Comment: Both canvas and gameobject should be in ui layer.

Comment: I gave that a try and it did nothing. I have no idea how that would do anything though since if they are both in the default layer by default and they didn't work right, putting them both in another layer together would not make a difference.

Comment: i thought they might be in different layers.

Answer (score 0):

You code seems fine, it might be problem related to the gameobject where this script is attached (because you are passing transform.position in Instantiate). it might be positioning the Instantiated game object off the canvas. Try like this once it might work.

```
intro = Instantiate (Resources.Load ("intro")) as GameObject;
```

and after setting its parent(very important), set it's position like this

```
intro.transform.localPosition = new vector3(0,0,0);
```

Comment: I tried all that you have said and it has not made any difference. It still shows up behind the other canvas objects.